# Facebook App hyperlinks

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

Should hyperlinks in a Facebook app be relative i.e. `<a href="profile.php">link</a>` or absolute i.e. `<a href="http://apps.facebook.com/apptitle/profile.php">link</a>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook app or not, the same rules apply. So, relative URLs should work.

Comment: Seems the Facebook example App, Run with Friends, uses relative

Answer (score 0):

If you use relative, it will load from within your iframe, so you will have to include the signed_request parameter to make sure subsequent pages can decode the sigs to get auth information. Using absolute links causes the chrome to refresh with every page change, which is additional load time on every page.